# If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, is it possible to have $I(n^2) = I(q^k) + c$, for some constant $c > 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, perfect-numbers

The title says it all.

> If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, is it possible to have $I(n^2) = I(q^k) + c$, for some constant $c > 0$?

Here $I(x)$ is defined to be the ratio
$$I(x) = \dfrac{\sigma(x)}{x} = \dfrac{\sum_{d \mid x}{d}}{x}.$$

Note that we have
$$I(q^k)I(n^2) = I(q^k n^2) = 2$$
since $\sigma(x)$ is *weakly multiplicative* and $N = q^k n^2$ is *perfect*.

**My Attempt**

Since the Euler prime $q$ satisfies $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we have $q \geq 5$.

In particular, this means that
$$1 < \dfrac{q + 1}{q} = I(q) \leq I(q^k) < \dfrac{q}{q - 1} \leq \dfrac{5}{4}$$
from which it follows that
$$\dfrac{8}{5} < I(n^2) = \dfrac{2}{I(q^k)} < 2.$$

Suppose that we have the equation
$$I(n^2) = I(q^k) + c.$$
Then we have
$$\dfrac{7}{20} = \dfrac{8}{5} - \dfrac{5}{4} < c = I(n^2) - I(q^k) < 2 - 1 = 1.$$
Also, from the equation
$$I(n^2) = I(q^k) + c,$$
we get
$$I(q^k)I(n^2) = \left(I(q^k)\right)^2 + c\cdot{I(q^k)}$$
by multiplying both sides by $I(q^k)$.
We also get
$$\left(I(n^2)\right)^2 = I(q^k)I(n^2) + c\cdot{I(n^2)}$$
by multiplying both sides by $I(n^2)$.
We get the equations
$$\left(I(q^k)\right)^2 + c\cdot{I(q^k)} - 2 = 0$$
and
$$\left(I(n^2)\right)^2 - c\cdot{I(n^2)} - 2 = 0.$$
We now use the quadratic formula to solve these two equations.
From the first equation, we get that
$$I(q^k) = \dfrac{-c \pm \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2}$$
while from the second equation, we obtain
$$I(n^2) = \dfrac{c \pm \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2}.$$

Since $7/20 < c < 1$, we have that

**(1)** $$-2 = \dfrac{-1 - 3}{2} = \dfrac{-1 - \sqrt{(1)^2 + 8}}{2} < I({q_1}^{k_1}) = \dfrac{-c - \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2} < \dfrac{-(7/20) - \sqrt{(7/20)^2 + 8}}{2} = \dfrac{-(7/20) -(57/20)}{2} = \dfrac{-64}{40} = -\dfrac{8}{5},$$
which contradicts $1 < I({q_1}^{k_1}) < 5/4$.  Hence,
$$I(q^k) \neq \dfrac{-c - \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2}.$$

**(2)** $$\dfrac{37}{40} = \dfrac{-1 + (57/20)}{2} = \dfrac{-1 + \sqrt{(7/20)^2 + 8}}{2} < I({q_2}^{k_2}) = \dfrac{-c + \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2} < \dfrac{-(7/20) + \sqrt{(1)^2 + 8}}{2} = \dfrac{(-7/20) + 3}{2} = \dfrac{53}{40}$$
which does not contradict $1 < I({q_2}^{k_2}) < 5/4$.  Hence,
$$I(q^k) = \dfrac{-c + \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2}.$$

**(3)** $$\dfrac{-53}{40} = \dfrac{(7/20) - 3}{2} = \dfrac{(7/20) - \sqrt{(1)^2 + 8}}{2} < I({n_1}^2) = \dfrac{c - \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2} < \dfrac{1 - \sqrt{(7/20)^2 + 8}}{2} = \dfrac{1 - (57/20)}{2} = -\dfrac{37}{40}$$
which contradicts $8/5 < I({n_1}^2) < 2$.  Hence,
$$I(n^2) \neq \dfrac{c - \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2}.$$

**(4)** $$\dfrac{8}{5} = \dfrac{64}{40} = \dfrac{(7/20) + (57/20)}{2} = \dfrac{(7/20) + \sqrt{(7/20)^2 + 8}}{2}< I({n_1}^2) = \dfrac{c + \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2} < \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{(1)^2 + 8}}{2} = \dfrac{1 + 3}{2} = 2$$
which does not contradict $8/5 < I({n_2}^2) < 2$.  Hence,
$$I(n^2) = \dfrac{c + \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2}.$$

We now check:
$$2 = I(q^k n^2) = I(q^k)I(n^2) = \left(\dfrac{-c + \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\dfrac{c + \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2}\right) = \dfrac{\left(\sqrt{c^2 + 8}\right)^2 - c^2}{4} = \dfrac{|c^2 + 8| - c^2}{4} = \dfrac{(c^2  + 8) - c^2}{4} = \dfrac{8}{4} = 2,$$
whence there is no contradiction.

Here is my question:

> Will it be possible to derive a contradiction from assuming
>   $$I(q^k) = \dfrac{-c + \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2}$$
>   and
>   $$I(n^2) = \dfrac{c + \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2},$$
>   where $7/20 < c = I(n^2) - I(q^k) < 1$ and $c$ is a constant?

Comment: Under the assumption $k=1$, I get
$$\dfrac{13}{15} = \dfrac{-1 + (43/15)}{2} = \dfrac{-1 + \sqrt{(7/15)^2 + 8}}{2} < I(q) = \dfrac{-c + \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2} < \dfrac{-(7/15) + \sqrt{(1)^2 + 8}}{2} = \dfrac{-(7/15) + 3}{2} = \dfrac{38}{30}$$
which is weaker than (and therefore, does not contradict) $1 < I(q) \leq 6/5$.

Comment: Edit:  When $k=1$, I have the bounds
$$\dfrac{7}{15} \leq c = I(n^2) - I(q) < 1$$
since $q \geq 5$ implies $1 < I(q) = 1 + (1/q) \leq 6/5 < 5/3 \leq 2/I(q) = I(n^2) < 2$.

Comment: Edit: When $k=1$, we have
$$\dfrac{5}{3} = \dfrac{50}{30} = \dfrac{(7/15) + (43/15)}{2} = \dfrac{(7/15) + \sqrt{(7/15)^2 + 8}}{2} \leq I(n^2) = \dfrac{c + \sqrt{c^2 + 8}}{2} < \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{(1)^2 + 8}}{2} = \dfrac{1 + 3}{2} = 2.$$

Comment: I note that
$$\dfrac{57}{20} < I(q^k) + I(n^2) = \sqrt{c^2 + 8} < 3$$
for $k > 1$, and that
$$\dfrac{43}{15} \leq I(q^k) + I(n^2) = I(q) + I(n^2) = \sqrt{c^2 + 8} < 3$$
for $k = 1$.

Comment: Lastly,
$$I(q) + I(n^2) = I(q) + \dfrac{2}{I(q)} = \dfrac{q+1}{q} + \dfrac{2q}{q+1} = \dfrac{(q+1)^2 + 2q^2}{q(q+1)} = \dfrac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q+1)}$$
and that
$$I(q) + I(n^2) = \dfrac{43}{15} = \dfrac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q+1)} \iff q = 5.$$

Comment: When $k > 1$, we have
$$\dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q -1)} = \dfrac{2(q-1)}{q} + \dfrac{q}{q - 1} < I(q^k) + I(n^2) < \dfrac{2q}{q+1} + \dfrac{q+1}{q} = I(q) + I(n^2),$$
which results to the contradiction
$$I(q^k) < I(q).$$

Comment: The previous comment has been cross-posted to [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243898).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we have
$$c = I(n^2) - I(q^k) = \dfrac{2}{I(q^k)} - I(q^k) = \dfrac{2 - \left(I(q^k)\right)^2}{I(q^k)} = \dfrac{2 - \left(\dfrac{q^{k+1} - 1}{{q^k}(q-1)}\right)^2}{\dfrac{q^{k+1} - 1}{{q^k}(q-1)}}$$
which is *not independent* of $k$ and $q$.  Hence, the difference $I(n^2) - I(q^k)$ is *not constant*.

In particular, even if $k=1$, we have
$$c' = I(n^2) - I(q) = \dfrac{2 - \left(\dfrac{q^{2} - 1}{{q}(q-1)}\right)^2}{\dfrac{q^{2} - 1}{{q}(q-1)}} = \dfrac{q^2 - 2q - 1}{q(q+1)},$$
which is still *dependent* on the *Euler prime* $q$.

In the same manner, for the case of *even perfect numbers* ${2^{p-1}}(2^p - 1)$, we have
$$d = I(2^{p-1}) - I(2^p - 1) = 2 - \dfrac{1}{2^{p-1}} - \left(1 + \dfrac{1}{2^p - 1}\right) = 1 - \dfrac{1}{2^{p-1}} - \dfrac{1}{2^p - 1},$$
which is *dependent* on $p$.